# django form validate username field from external database

Tags: django, validation, rawsql

I am building this django app and I have a form that allows users to input a 32 character api key. I am using an external database that has these api key values in a table. I would like to validate that the api key is correct as soon as the user puts in a value in the CharField.

this is the field I am using at the moment which is pretty simple.

```
apikey = forms.CharField(label='User api key', required=True)
```

I have the external database configure in my settings.py and have imported some database lookup functions into in to my forms.py. I already have ChoiceFeilds being populated by database values for example.

What is the best way go about checking that the api key is in my external database and if not, display a error message when the users puts in a api key that is not in the database?

Thanks - Oli

Comment: Can't you use form fields `clean()` method to check existing keys?

Comment: So I use a specific function for that field to validate the data and this will work only when the form is submitted? for example this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute. I could do that and I will give it a go. I was just interested to see how it could be done on the client side and what tools you would use to do that. I actually have a few fields I need to validate in the form so would rather do it there and then. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: May you write another view just to check the username and use ajax to send the user's value and validate it.

Comment: cool - I will look in to that. As you can probably tell, I'm not experienced an django coder so I'm not fully aware of how to do these things but if what you have just mentioned will work, I will go and figure it out.